# Abp.io Data seeder from external module

Tags: abp

Abp.io data seeder works when the class implementing `IDataSeedContributor` is in the *.Domain project, but it's not being executed when the class is in another `AbpModule`.

Is there a way to tell Abp to check my module when searching for seeders?

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/4.4/Data-Seeding

Answer (score 1):

If you need to seed a data related to an other domain, it means you are dependent on to an other module. You need to add reference of the Domain project of the other module.

If you don't care about DDD layering or bounded contexts seperation to seed, just create a **shared** project and add your *DataSeedContributors* and reference to that project.

They will get executed as long as you have reference.